# jqGrid Treegrid date sorting does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.4.0 and jQuery 1.7.2 (also i tried lastest version jqgrid and jquery). I use treegrid like that:

```
    jQuery('#projects_grid').jqGrid({
                treeGrid: true,
                treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
                ExpandColumn: 'ProjectName',
                url: 'jqGridTestHandler.ashx?q=tree',
                treedatatype: 'xml',
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: ['RID', l_('ProjectName'), l_('CustomerName'), l_('StartDate'), l_('EndDate'), l_('ManagerName'), l_('SourceLang'), l_('TargetLang'), l_('DomainName'), '', ''],
                colModel: [
{ name: 'RID', index: 'RID', hidden: true, key: true },
{ name: 'ProjectName', index: 'ProjectName' },
{ name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName' },
{ name: 'StartDate', index: 'StartDate', width: '80px', align: 'center'},
{ name: 'EndDate', index: 'EndDate', width: '80px', align: 'center' },
{ name: 'FullName', index: 'FullName', align: 'center' },
{ name: 'SourceLang', index: 'SourceLang', width: '110px', align: 'center', formatter: flagFormatter },
{ name: 'TargetLang', index: 'TargetLang', width: '110px', align: 'center', formatter: flagFormatter },
{ name: 'DomainName', index: 'DomainName', width: '110px', align: 'center', formatter: domainNameFormatter },
{ name: 'IsExternal', index: 'IsExternal', hidden: true },
{ name: 'myac', fixed: true, sortable: false, resize: false, width: '30px'}],
                height: '345px',
                loaded: false,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                pager: '#projects_pager',
                rowNum: 10,
                autowidth: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                altRows: true,
                toolbar: [true, 'top'],
                ExpandRowClick: true,
...some events (loadcomplete etc..)
```

and my data source like that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rows>
<page>1</page><total>1</total><records>4</records>
<row>
<cell>B55A6056261913D62648F2730C2766B2</cell>
<cell>Test Projectname1</cell>
<cell>Test Customer</cell>
<cell>18.02.2013</cell>
<cell>28.02.2013</cell>
<cell>Frank</cell>
<cell>en-GB</cell>
<cell>tr-TR</cell>
<cell>Law</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[NULL]]></cell>
<cell>true</cell>
<cell>false</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell>21142DEE531B2313FC9356C3B000B54D</cell>
<cell>Test Projectname2</cell>
<cell>Test Customer</cell>
<cell>05.04.2013</cell>
<cell>06.04.2013</cell>
<cell>Frank</cell>
<cell>en-GB</cell>
<cell>tr-TR</cell>
<cell>Law</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[NULL]]></cell>
<cell>true</cell>
<cell>false</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell>5FF805CE71B0A459C83734735B990E8C</cell>
<cell>Test Projectname3</cell>
<cell>Test Customer</cell>
<cell>22.04.2013</cell>
<cell>27.04.2013</cell>
<cell>Frank</cell>
<cell>en-GB</cell>
<cell>tr-TR</cell>
<cell>Law</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[NULL]]></cell>
<cell>false</cell>
<cell>false</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell>BCD36ABFA07CE94089F6C5B743C57608</cell>
<cell>Test Projectname4</cell>
<cell>Test Customer</cell>
<cell>27.04.2013</cell>
<cell>28.04.2013</cell>
<cell>Frank</cell>
<cell>en-GB</cell>
<cell>tr-TR</cell>
<cell>Law</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell>0</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[NULL]]></cell>
<cell>true</cell>
<cell>false</cell>
</row>
</rows>
```

So my problem is date column sorting. I've done some search in stackoverflow, i found some solutions but they didn't work my case.

Unsorted list like that:

```
18.02.2013
05.04.2013
22.04.2013
27.04.2013
```

Sorted like that:

```
05.04.2013
18.02.2013
22.04.2013
27.04.2013
```

What do i wrong?

Comment: Data type of your date column is not of type `date`. change the datatype to `date` from `varchar`. After that you have to format your date withing cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `formatter: "date"` with correct `formatoptions` in `'StartDate'` and `'EndDate'` columns. The current setting (default options) inform jqGrid to interpret the data as string. To have correct sorting of the dates in format like `22.04.2013` you should include the following additional properties in the column definition:

```js
formatter: "date", formatoptions: { srcformat: "d.m.Y", newformat: "d.m.Y" }
```

Comment: Thank you Oleg and @Amit Garg. I've combine both of your's answers and that worked correctly. Final code: `sorttype: 'date' , formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd.m.Y', newformat: 'd.m.Y'}`